# How to have both table and graph in line inside a tabpanel?

Tags: r, shiny

Im working on a R shiny app and require to have both a data table and a plotly graph in line.

My code has a tab approach but im usure in how can i have both elements in line

```
              tabPanel("Direccionamientos",
                       h3("Direccionamientos totales para el periodo"), 
                       downloadButton("myfiledownload3", label = "Descargar detalle"),
                       DT::dataTableOutput("table3"),
                       plotlyOutput('plot2'))
```

[image]

Comment: [`fluidRow()`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/fluidPage.html) and [`column()`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/column.html) are your friends.

Comment: I have also found [this reference](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html) on grid layout in `shiny` to be useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Limey, you can use a fluidRow layout with two columns of width 6 each. (the total value should add up to 12)

example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
    tabPanel("Direccionamientos",
             h3("Direccionamientos totales para el periodo"), 
             downloadButton("myfiledownload3", label = "Descargar detalle"),
             fluidRow(column(width = 6,
             DT::dataTableOutput("table3")),
             column(width = 6, plotlyOutput('plot2')))
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
    output$table3 <- renderDT({iris})
    output$plot2  <- renderPlotly({ggplotly(ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Width, color = Species)) + geom_point())})
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```